# Включение кнопки при вводе текста

Tags: java, javafx

Задача собственно такая:
Имеется основное поле ввода `TextField surnameNamePatronymicID` - принимает ФИО, имеется кнопка
`Button fillButtonAction` - именуемая "заполнить"
При нажатии на кнопку "заполнить" парсится введенное (разбивается по пробелам) и в массив, далее из массива в нужные поля, далее из этих полей в нужные `TextField`.

```
this.fullName = textField.getText();
String[] fullNameArr = this.fullName.split("\\s");
this.surname = fullNameArr[0];
this.name = fullNameArr[1];
this.patronymic = fullNameArr[2];
```

Собственно вопрос в чем, нужна некая защита от "дурака", корректный ввод.
Сейчас реализовал так, если поле `TextField surnameNamePatronymicID` пустое, то кнопка "заполнить" не активна.

```
...
@FXML
    private TextField surnameNamePatronymicID;
@FXML
    private Button fillButtonAction;

    public void initialize() {
        fillButtonAction.disableProperty().bind(surnameNamePatronymicID.textProperty().isEmpty());
    }

@FXML
    private void fillButtonAction() throws IOException {
...
```

Но хочется чтобы было такая проверка, к примеру:
**текст " " текст " " текст**
и только после этого кнопка становится активной, т.е. ввели Иванов Иван Иванович и кнопка стала активной.

Так же если есть другие варианты проверки правильности ввода - приветствуются!

Другими словами, как заставить пользователя ввести корректно ФИО?

Comment: вешайте слушатель на нажатие кнопок  клавиатуры и в нем проверяйте, что введено на данный момент. в чем вопрос то?

Comment: вы знаете , что такое слушатель?

Comment: в общих чертах на любой компонет вьюхи вы можете повесить слушатель. слушатель - это паттерн, который позволяет уведомить о произошедшем событии. в данном случае слушатель нужен на текством поле ввода, наблюдаемое событие - нажатие кнопок клавиатуры. посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982895/how-to-use-keyevent-in-javafx-project

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете поставить слушатель на ваш TextField

```
surnameNamePatronymicID.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                try{String s = surnameNamePatronymicID.getText();
                    if(s.length()>5){ 
                        // Не менее 5 символов
                        fillButtonAction.setDisable(false);
                        return;
                    }
                    fillButtonAction.setDisable(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    fillButtonAction.setDisable(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Всю эту богодельню, конечно лучше поместить в отдельный класс/метод, и вызвать с помощью лямбды. Метод должен принимать ссылки на  TextField и ваш button

```
    surnameNamePatronymicID.setOnKeyReleased(event -> YourClass.method(surnameNamePatronymicID,fillButtonAction)); 
//Пример вызова метода ( альтернатива варианту выше )
```

Надеюсь вы справитесь с тем что нужно написать в методе другого класса.

*Отмечу так же, что лучше использовать setOnKeyReleased, так вы гарантированно получите последний нажатый символ.*

Comment: Это хороший вариант, но учитывает только нажатие клавиш. Например пользователь может ввести текст копи-пастом или через контекстное меню TextField

Answer (score 1):

Поставить слушатель на изменение **текста** TextField.

```
surnameNamePatronymicID.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if(newValue.length()<5) {
                // good
            }else {
                // bad
            }
        }
    });
```

Этот обработчик вызывается при любом изменение текста. Например если пользователь захочет сделать копи-паст это все равно будет работать.